# Spring Boot @SpringBootApplication Annotation is not working for classes in different packages

Tags: spring-boot

I am developing a sample SpringBoot Application. I have two packages
1. com.A( in which main class annotated with @springbootApplication is there)
2. com.B(other spring beans).

Now My query is : Spring beans which are in package B are not getting scanned because of that application failing.I tried using 
  a. @springbootapplicatio(scanBasePackages="com.B")
  b. Also @componentScan(..)
  c. Used @EnableConfiguration  also.

However If I move B package beans under A package,then everything works fine(because @springbootapplication takes care of that).

Please help me to resolve this!

Rahul Kumar

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration class containing the @SpringbootApplication annotation will scan all the classes in the same package in which it is present . You can mention the base package name with the annotation and try it ..

Something like below:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.basepackage"})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.A", com.B"})
```